# RegEx for reading SRT file in android

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to get the start time, end time and subtitle from subtitle file(.srt) in a android app. I'm using the regex for extracting the content.  I placed the .srt file in assets folder. But the pattern didn't extract any content from the file. It is returning null. Is there any modification needed in regEx. The regex code and file content given below,

code::

```
protected static final String nl = "\\\n";
protected static final String sp = "[ \\t]*";
Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("(\\d+)" + sp + nl
                    + "(\\d{1,2}):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d)" + sp
                    + "-->" + sp + "(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d)" + sp
                    + "(X1:\\d.*?)??" + nl + "((.|\\\\n)*?)" + nl + nl);
```

file content::

```
2
00:00:02,373 --> 00:00:03,999
Ohh wooaah

3
00:00:06,190 --> 00:00:07,798
Ohh wooaah


4
00:00:09,743 --> 00:00:12,966
Ohh wooaah
```

Comment: Could you please provide the file's content ? What do you want to extract ?

Comment: 2
00:00:02,373 --> 00:00:03,999
Ohh wooaah

3
00:00:06,190 --> 00:00:07,798
Ohh wooaah


4
00:00:09,743 --> 00:00:12,966
Ohh wooaah

Comment: "What do you want to extract" -> please be more precise when asking a question.

Comment: i want to get the start time , end time and subtitle

Comment: Great ! Now edit your question, and append those information in a readable way. The example you have just provided probably contains some line feeds, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next time, provide what you've tried at least, and BTW here's a very good tutorial on regexp : http://www.regular-expressions.info/

```
String lineNumberPattern = "(\\d+\\s)";
String timeStampPattern = "([\\d:,]+)";
String contentPattern = "(.*\s.*)";

// the complete regexp : "(\\d+\\s)([\\d:,]+)( --> )([\\d:,]+)(\\s)(.*\s.*)"

String sampleLine = "2\n00:00:02,373 --> 00:00:03,999\nOhh wooaah\n";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(lineNumberPattern + timeStampPattern + "( --> )" + timeStampPattern + "(\\s)" + contentPattern).matcher(sampleLine);

while(matcher.find()) {
    String start = matcher.group(2);
    String end = matcher.group(4);
    String content = matcher.group(6);
    // store those information somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer here for more info on regular e http://www.regexr.com/